# What is the name of the guitar song plays in the beginning of After the Rain episode 2?

Tags: music, after-the-rain

There's a guitar song that plays in the beginning of *After the Rain* episode 2.

What is the name of the song?

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. Since you mentioned "tab", I assume it's a guitar song, but we need your clarification. Also, if possible, please also mention the timestamp to make it clear which song you mean.

Comment: [The soundtrack](https://vgmdb.net/album/74344) doesn't come out until April 18, so you'll likely have to wait until then to find out. (Or at least until previews from the soundtrack become available, which may happen sooner.)

Comment: yes. guitar tab and the song starts at the beginning at 0:06

Answer (score 1):

The name of the song is *Saka wo Iku Bus*.

I am so grateful for the people who created this beautiful anime and OST.